# Upload multiple files and if I leave any of the image blank or don't upload anything, a default image should be there

Tags: php, mysql

I want to upload multiple files on single button click, and also if I leave any of the image blank or if I do not upload anything, a default image should be there. But code is not working properly:

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');
$date = date('Y-m-d');

$s1=$_FILES['image']['name'];
$s2=$_FILES['image1']['name'];
$s3=$_FILES['image2']['name'];
$s4=$_FILES['image3']['name'];
$s5=$_FILES['image4']['name'];
$s6=$_FILES['image5']['name'];
$s7=$_FILES['image6']['name'];
$s8=$_FILES['image7']['name'];
$s9=$_FILES['image8']['name'];
$s10=$_FILES['image9']['name'];

$path="images/".$s1;
$path1="images/".$s2;
$path2="images/".$s3;
$path3="images/".$s4;
$path4="images/".$s5;
$path5="images/".$s6;
$path6="images/".$s7;
$path7="images/".$s8;
$path8="images/".$s9;
$path9="images/".$s10;

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],$path);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image1']['tmp_name'],$path1);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image2']['tmp_name'],$path2);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image3']['tmp_name'],$path3);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image4']['tmp_name'],$path4);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image5']['tmp_name'],$path5);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image6']['tmp_name'],$path6);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image7']['tmp_name'],$path7);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image8']['tmp_name'],$path8);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image9']['tmp_name'],$path9);

$default_image = "images/default_img.png";

if(!($s1==""  ))
{
    $q="insert into form(id, image1, image2, image3, image4, image5, image6, image7, image8, image9, image10, date)values
    ('','$default_image','$path1','$path2','$path3','$path4','$path5','$path6','$path7','$path8','$path9','$date')";    
}
else if(!($s2==""))
{
    $q="insert into form(id,  image1, image2, image3, image4, image5, image6, image7, image8, image9, image10, date)values
    ('','$default_image','$path2','$path3','$path4','$path5','$path6','$path7','$path8','$path9','$date')"; 
}
else if(!($s3=="")) 
{
    $q="insert into form(id, image1, image2, image3, image4, image5, image6, image7, image8, image9, image10, date)values
    ('','$path','$path1','$default_image','$path3','$path4','$path5','$path6','$path7','$path8','$path9','$date')"; 
}
else if(!($s4==""))
{
    $q="insert into form(id, image1, image2, image3, image4, image5, image6, image7, image8, image9, image10, date)values
    ('','$path',$path1','$path2','$default_image','$path4','$path5','$path6','$path7','$path8','$path9','$date')";  
}
else if(!($s5==""))
{
    $q="insert into form(id, image1, image2, image3, image4, image5, image6, image7, image8, image9, image10, date)values
    ('','$path','$path1','$path2','$path3','$default_image','$path5','$path6','$path7','$path8','$path9','$date')"; 
}
else if(!($s6==""))
{
    $q="insert into form(id, image1, image2, image3, image4, image5, image6, image7, image8, image9, image10, date)values
    ('','$path','$path1','$path2','$path3','$path4','$default_image','$path6','$path7','$path8','$path9','$date')"; 
}
else if(!($s7==""))
{
    $q="insert into form(id, image1, image2, image3, image4, image5, image6, image7, image8, image9, image10, date)values
    ('','$path','$path1','$path2','$path3','$path4','$path5','$default_image','$path7','$path8','$path9','$date')"; 
}
else if(!($s8==""))
{
    $q="insert into form(id,image1, image2, image3, image4, image5, image6, image7, image8, image9, image10, date)values
    ('','$path','$path1','$path2','$path3','$path4','$path5','$path6','$default_image','$path8','$path9','$date')"; 
}
else if(!($s9==""))
{
    $q="insert into form(id, image1, image2, image3, image4, image5, image6, image7, image8, image9, image10, date)values
    ('','$path','$path1','$path2','$path3','$path4','$path5','$path6','$path7','$default_image','$path9','$date')"; 
}
else if(!($s10==""))
{
    $q="insert into form(id, image1, image2, image3, image4, image5, image6, image7, image8, image9, image10, date)values
    ('','$path','$path1','$path2','$path3','$path4','$path5','$path6','$path7','$path8','$default_image','$date')"; 
}
else{
    $q="insert into form(id, image1, image2, image3, image4, image5, image6, image7, image8, image9, image10, date)values
    ('','$path','$path1','$path2','$path3','$path4','$path5','$path6','$path7','$path8','$path9','$date')";
}$e=mysql_query($q);
if($e>0)
{
    header("location:registration.php?msg=insertion sucess");
}
else
{
    header("location:registration.php?msg=insertion fail");
}
?>
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: By the way, this code really needs refactorization, add some arrays and loops, for example for `$path` creation, calls of `move_uploaded_file` et cetera.

Answer (score 0):

what does the page look like? you will probably need to post more info (actual output, any error messages from the server, if row was actually inserted, etc.,), but if the page is blank my guess that it is probably because your `$s1` to `$s9` variables are not actually equal to ''. try an `echo $s1;` and see what the output is when the field is left empty

Comment: hi.......   example we have 10 upload options, and we want to upload first 5 images.   and want to keep rest 5 upload options empty.   the  6th option only is picking the default image set by us as an empty one , and the rest 4 options are not picking deafult image set by us for empty options.. might be "else if" conditions are not working properly. please give ur views asap

Comment: OK, I see your issue. Please Please Please consider refactoring this code it is very long and repetitive, use arrays for the values and loops to iterate over the arrays. picture six is the only one showing because of the else if, removing the else in each if statement would make only the 9th one show the default. you need to verify each `s` value whether it is null or empty and assign the paths the default path based on this.